# Runtime Error 1004 Unable to get PivotTable Property of the Worksheet class

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am using a Macro to create a pivot table and am running into the Runtime Error 1004, and no idea why. Any and all help would be appreciated

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "CTQ_Weekly_Attendance!R1C1:R1000C12", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12). _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="", TableName:="PivotTable2", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
Sheets("By_Title_&_Level").Activate
Cells(1, 1).Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Title")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Level_")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Picked_Up"), "Sum of Picked_Up", xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Attended"), "Sum of Attended", xlSum
ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The macro recorder is not great when it comes to pivot tables - you typically want to split up the pivot cache and pivot table creation into separate steps, and your code will always benefit from the use of a few variables:

```vb
Sub Pivot()

    Dim wb As Workbook, pc As PivotCache, pt As PivotTable
    Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsPivot As Worksheet
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsPivot = wb.Worksheets("By_Title_&_Level")
    Set wsData = wb.Worksheets("CTQ_Weekly_Attendance")
    
    Set pc = wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                              SourceData:=wsData.Range("A1:L1000"), _
                              Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12)
              
    Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=wsPivot.Range("B3"), _
                                 TableName:="PivotTable2", _
                                 DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12)

    With pt.PivotFields("Title")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    
    With pt.PivotFields("Level_")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With
    
    pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields("Picked_Up"), "Sum of Picked_Up", xlSum
    pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields("Attended"), "Sum of Attended", xlSum
    wb.ShowPivotTableFieldList = True

End Sub
```